Books on Qualities to look for in a Spouse
Which sefarim talk about the qualities a man should look for in a wife (and vice versa).
Do these still apply today?

You shouldn't marry a woman exactly your height because one of the requirements for a rebellious son is that his parents are the same height.

similar https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/35819/759

Here are some books on the subject in English:

Shidduchim and Zivugim by R' Yehuda Lebovits (1987)
The River Kettle and the Bird by R' Aharon Feldman (1987)
Don't Judge a Book by Its Cover by R' Mordechai Dolinsky (2006)

Perhaps there are newer books with more bells and whistles.
